# Updating external links and file locations Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I kinda have two questions in one.

I am creating a main budget file, budget files for specific districts aswell as report files connected to these district budgets.

The budgets are to be created for each district, so the main file is basicly just for a complete overview of budget and sales. There are about 30 districts, so quite a lot of files to connect.

-The report files gather data from a workbook in which sales are added, aswell as from the budget file for that specific district.

-The main budget adds the combined data from the different budget files and also gathers data from the sales workbook.

-The district budget files gather data from the sales workbook as a basis for the budget.

So first of all:
When the files are opened and I am prompted to activate content or update content. This will result in value errors unless I go to Data > Links > Open Files. For the main budget that means opening all 30 budget files to update everything.
Is there a way to make automate this process so that the files update without having to open all connected files?

Second:
I am creating this on my laptop and I am not sure how this is gonna be set up later. When I move the files, the connections will probably be lost since I am using formulas like SUMIFS etc. Is there a way to make the files search for the connected files without having to change every formula in a cell every time a file is moved?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You could write VBA code to open all the files you need at once, then update and save your main sheet.  If you aren't familiar with VBA, that would very much be a simple and straightforward intro project.

Also as far as moving sheets around, you are asking about Relative vs. Absolute paths.  I would suggest reading more about that here: [Relative vs. Absolute paths](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328440/description-of-link-management-and-storage-in-excel)

Comment: Thank you very much!

I have done some basic VBA codes before but not enought that I know how to write such a code. Would you happen to know how?